# Find through array in array field

Tags: arrays, angular

How can I find something through some arrays that also contain an array?
To be more precisely:

[image]

And I want to return from the coaches array, the id(within the coaches) that matches the username. What I've tried:

```
  if (!(args['coach'].value === '') && (args['coach'].value !== null)) {
    coachId = this.items.find(x => x.username === args.coach.value).id;
  }
```

Basically `this.items` is what I've console.log before. Now it gives me undefined.

Has someone a fix for this? Thank you very much.

```
[
   {
      "id":584,
      "name":"Name",
      "coaches":[
         {
            "id":8587,
            "username":"test"
         },
         {
            "id":8589,
            "username":"test1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":587,
      "name":"O1",
      "coaches":[

      ]
   }
]
```

And let s say I want to return the id `8587` when searching for the name `test`.

Comment: can you paste this.items JSON

Comment: @Sajeetharan edited the question.

Comment: 8587 for example if I am searching with the name test.

Comment: data.map(it => it.coaches.find(it2 => it2.username == "test")).filter(it => !!it).map(it=> it.id)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Uzer I think in the question it is referring to `id` of `coaches` array, not the `id` of main `items` arrays. So your solution wouldn't work.

Comment: ah yes your probably right. So no good solutions yet.

Comment: Oh yep.. only know I see. :(

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let y = this.items.filter(o => o.coaches.some(e => e.username === 'test'))[0]
            .coaches.filter(e=>e.username === 'test')[0].id;

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine `map` and `find`:

```
const array = [
  [{a1: 1},
   {a2: 2}
  ],
  [{a1: 1},
   {a2: 2},
   {a3: 3}]
];

const element = array.map(innerArray => {
  const found = innerArray.find(el => el.a1 === 1);
  if (found) return found.a1;
  return null;
}).find(el => el !== null);

console.log(element) // 1
```

Comment: I got the error message: `innerArray.find is not a function`

Comment: You have to adjust it for your object

Answer (score 3):

For finding multiple matches do as follows:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 584,
    "name": "Name",
    "coaches": [{
        "id": 8587,
        "username": "test"
      },
      {
        "id": 8589,
        "username": "test1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 587,
    "name": "O1",
    "coaches": [

    ]
  }
];

const usernameToSearch = 'test1';

const foundCoachIds = data
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {

    // Destructure the coaches property first
    const {
      coaches,
      ...rest
    } = curr;

    // Check if any username matches the coach
    const foundMatches = coaches.filter(x => x.username === usernameToSearch);

    // If there is any found match push into accumulator
    if (foundMatches.length) {
      for (const foundMatch of foundMatches) {
        if (acc.indexOf(foundMatch.id) === -1) {
          acc.push(foundMatch.id);
        }
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(foundCoachIds);
```

Comment: Nice solution, you can just use `find` in place of `filter` and drop the `|| []` as much as the `[0]`

Comment: Does this deal with more than one hit? I dont think it does. Not the best answer imo

Comment: @Uzer what do you mean by one hit ? I didnt get ?

Comment: reg. this line `if (foundCoach[0] && foundCoach[0].id)`, what if the `username` is found in second element of `coaches` array?

Comment: Exactly, its probably an issue due to the lack of context from the OP, but there could be more than one id, in the coaches sub array. There could even be 3 or more hits, if the 2nd item in the outer array had a coaches entry with the target username

Comment: @Uzer modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
const data = [
   {
      "id":584,
      "name":"Name",
      "coaches":[
         {
            "id":8587,
            "username":"test"
         },
         {
            "id":8589,
            "username":"test1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":587,
      "name":"O1",
      "coaches":[

      ]
   }
];
```

For outer id

```
data.map(it => {return !!it.coaches.find(it2 => it2.username == "test") ? it.id : null}).filter(it=>!!it)

evaluates to [584]
```

For inner 
(coaches) id:

```
data.map(it => it.coaches.find(it2 => it2.username == "test")).filter(it => !!it).map(it=> it.id) 

returns [8587]
```

Just need to take the first item from these to get your answer.

Comment: For some reason it gives me [number];

Comment: Yes, the id within the coaches array.

Comment: that was my first answer in the comments... nevermind